# probability: transformation of a random variable $Y = X^4 + 1$

Tags: probability, transformation

> Find the PDF of $Y = X^4 + 1$ if $X\sim\exp(\lambda)$.

---

When a transformation is not one-to-one, we have multiple solutions for $X$.  Take for example $Y = X^2$. Then
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= \sqrt{y}\\
x_2 &= -\sqrt{y}
\end{align*}
Now $Y = X^4 + 1$ isn't one-to-one since $Y = 2$ when $X= \pm 1, \pm i$.  However, I don't see what my $x_i$s would be for $X = \sqrt[4]{Y - 1}$.

Comment: This is not a good example, since our function is one to one on the part of the world where the exponential distribution lives.

Comment: I am sorry but the question is very unclear to me. You want the pdf of $Y$? Given one $X$, there is a unique $Y$. What is the problem?

Comment: @gmath the questions is at the top so I dont know how it isnt clear to you.

Comment: @AndréNicolas this is a problem from a book.

Comment: @dustin: Not the actual question, but what you are asking about it.

Comment: @gmath Did you not read what I wrote? I am stating what one must do when a it isn't one to one, giving an example that I know how it works, and then saying I dont see how the $x_i$s are constructed for the problem I am dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}F_Y(y)&=P\left(X^4+1\le y\right)=P\left(|X|\le \sqrt[4]{y-1}\right)=P\left(-\sqrt[4]{y-1}\le X\le \sqrt[4]{y-1}\right)=\\&=F_X\left(\sqrt[4]{y-1}\right)-F_X\left(-\sqrt[4]{y-1}\right)\end{align*}$$ but since $F_X(x)=0$, for $x<0$ the above reduces to $$F_Y(y)=F_X\left(\sqrt[4]{y-1}\right)$$ for $y\ge1$. Hence $$f_Y(y)=f_X\left(\sqrt[4]{y-1}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt[4]{y-1}\right)'=λe^{-λ\sqrt[4]{y-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{(y-1)^3}}$$ for $y> 1$.

Comment: It is not real when y<1. What do you mean?

Comment: So I ended up with:  \begin{align*}
    p_Y(y)
    &= p_X\sum_{i = 1}^2\big(g_i^{-1}(y)\big)
       \Big\lvert\frac{dg_i^{-1}(y)}{dy}\Big\rvert\\
    &= p_X\big(\sqrt{Y -1}\big)\frac{1}{4(Y - 1)^{3/4}} +
       p_X\big(-\sqrt{Y -1}\big)\frac{1}{4(Y - 1)^{3/4}}\\
    &= \frac{1}{4\sqrt{Y - 1}}\exp\Big[x\sqrt{Y - 1}\Big] -
       \frac{1}{4\sqrt{Y - 1}}\exp\Big[-x\sqrt{Y - 1}\Big]\\
    &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{Y - 1}}\sinh\Big[x\sqrt{Y - 1}\Big]
  \end{align*}

Comment: what is the sum for?

Comment: that is something different from what I posted above, and it is not correct in your case (I do not say that your book is wrong).

Comment: I am looking at the example in the book for finding the PDF $Y = X^2$ and $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.  Since the transformation isn't one to one, we have multiple solutions in $x$ which are $x_1 = -\sqrt{y}$ and $x_2 = \sqrt{y}$.  Since both $x$ intervals map into the same $y$ interval and the $x$ intervals are disjoint, we have to sum $p_Y(y)$.

Comment: Yes, but the normal can take negative values. The exponential cannot!!

Comment: So we can just toss the other solution?

Comment: I do not even understand what you mean when you say toss... Good luck with it dude